# Is FlywayDB or Liquibase used for Cross DB Migration?

Tags: database-migration, liquibase, flyway, database-mirroring, cross-database

I'm working on a project, which is planned to use/manage 3 different databases [MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle] as the back-end. Now I have finished with my database design and everything I have set in with MySQL database.

Now I have to migrate / clone to SQL Server & Oracle as well. Also, I need the system to update automatically, whatever changes I will make in MySQL database [structural, not data] to be replicated in SQL Server & Oracle as well.

I couldn't find anything worthy from the documentations of FlywayDB and Liquibase, rather than a database source control mechanism.

So can I go for / get support from FlyWayDB or Liquibase to do this? Or is there an alternative for this task? Please advise.

Comment: My understanding is that Flyway does not have a DBMS independent format for the scripts - only plain SQL scripts. Liquibase has a DBMS independent XML format and knows how to map e.g. data types to different DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

Liquibase is easier to manage different kind of databases because it use XML to describe structure.
Flyway use SQL rather than XML to keep the syntax as simple as possible

In your case, you probably have to adapt your data structure to be compatible with your 3 databases. Oracle is one of the most restrictive.

Flyway could be a better solution because you don't care about historic modifications and because you have a better knowneldge of sql